# How to GetVariable() flash class variable?

Tags: javascript, flash

I want to use javascript flash method GetVariable() to get variable from flash.

I can get variable "foo" from default timeline by GetVariable("/:foo").

But I don't know how to get class static variable "bar" from this actionscript

```
package abc
{
    class def
    {
        public static var bar:Number;
    }
}
```

If you could provide reference link is plus. I found only few useful information via google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetVariable goes back to Flash 4.0 (maybe 3.0) - it's really only still there for backwards compatibility, you won't get it to work with AS2 or AS3. iirc, you couldn't even get a var from a movie clip (in other words, an object property), such as _root.myMovie.myVar. It would only get variables in the root. I remember throwing all of my vars up there so I could access them.

As the previous poster said, EI is your best bet. Other workarounds would be to set the var in the root so you can access it, or set the var in JS directly from AS (if you aren't doing this every 20ms or something).

Answer (score 1):

You can use ExternalInterface to set this up without using GetVariable().

Here's a link to Adobe's documentation about ExternalInterface.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=19_External_Interface_04.html